# How to group array by identical elements?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array with following elements:

```
array = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, nil, 3, 3]
```

I want to group them by matching elements and assign it to a hash. The output should look something like this:

```
{ one: [1, 1], two: [2, 2], three: [3, 3, 3], none: [nil] }
```

Note: `array` can only contain `1`, `2`, `3` and `nil` elements.

The keys (`:one`, `:two`, `:three`, `:none`) can be hard-coded.

Comment: Why do you need this weird and redundant data structure? Wouldn't be better if you had counts of each element? Like this: `{1 => 2, 2 => 1, 3 => 3, nil => 1}`

Comment: What is your question? What is the logic for the keys? What is the logic that determines the number of elements in the array?

Comment: @sawa This is requirement to generate a hash like this.

Comment: Any reason to down vote the question ?

Comment: I have updated the question. Actually this array can only contain 1,2,3 and nil values. So there is no logic behind the keys. Keys can be hard coded.

Comment: Why is there only one `2` in the output?

Comment: @stefan Thanks, updated the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) the array (elements) by [`itself`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-itself):

```
array = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, nil, 3, 3]
hash = array.group_by(&:itself)
#=> {1=>[1, 1], 2=>[2, 2], 3=>[3, 3, 3], nil=>[nil]}
```

Afterwards, you can use [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) to "rename" the keys:

```
keys = { 1 => :one, 2 => :two, 3 => :three, nil => :none }
hash.map { |k, v| [keys[k], v] }.to_h
#=> {:one=>[1, 1], :two=>[2, 2], :three=>[3, 3, 3], :none=>[nil]}
```

Comment: for `itself` ruby 2.2+ is required it won't work for older version. 1+ for `itself`

Comment: I'm using 2.1.6. So, I'm getting undefined method `itself' for 1:Fixnum

Comment: @Arif just use `group_by { |e| e }` in that case

Comment: @Stefan Thanks, exactly what i want.

Answer (score 1):

Coming from a Perl background, I'm used to obfuscated ways to munge arrays and hashes. Here's how it damaged me:

Using `group_by` is the obvious way to find the similarities:

```
array = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, nil, 3, 3]
hash = array.group_by{ |i| i } # => {1=>[1, 1], 2=>[2, 2], 3=>[3, 3, 3], nil=>[nil]}
```

Using a hash is the easy way to map from one thing to another:

```
new_keys = {
  1   => :one,
  2   => :two,
  3   => :three,
  nil => :none
}
```

Here's where the Perl influence affects my mind:

```
new_keys.values.zip(hash.values_at(*new_keys.keys)).to_h    # => {:one=>[1, 1], :two=>[2, 2], :three=>[3, 3, 3], :none=>[nil]}
new_keys.each_with_object({}){ |(k, v), h| h[v] = hash[k] } # => {:one=>[1, 1], :two=>[2, 2], :three=>[3, 3, 3], :none=>[nil]}
new_keys.inject({}){ |h, (k, v)| h[v] = hash[k]; h }        # => {:one=>[1, 1], :two=>[2, 2], :three=>[3, 3, 3], :none=>[nil]}
```

Because they all do the same thing, but in different ways, I wanted to know what was fastest. And, because I like @Stefan's `map` approach I wanted to see if there was any advantage speed-wise for a particular method:

```
require 'fruity'

5.times do

  compare do
    _zip              { new_keys.values.zip(hash.values_at(*new_keys.keys)).to_h    }
    _each_with_object { new_keys.each_with_object({}){ |(k, v), h| h[v] = hash[k] } }
    _inject           { new_keys.inject({}){ |h, (k, v)| h[v] = hash[k]; h }        }
    _map              { hash.map { |k, v| [new_keys[k], v] }.to_h                   }
  end

  puts
end
```

Fruity wasn't able to find any remarkable speed differences, and background tasks were affecting the ability to find consistent differences so I ran the comparison five times. The minor differences are hinted at by the order of the results, but any of these look like a good way to go:

```
# >> Running each test 2048 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> _each_with_object is similar to _inject
# >> _inject is faster than _zip by 19.999999999999996% ± 10.0%
# >> _zip is faster than _map by 10.000000000000009% ± 10.0%
# >> 
# >> Running each test 2048 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> _each_with_object is similar to _inject
# >> _inject is similar to _zip
# >> _zip is similar to _map
# >> 
# >> Running each test 2048 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> _inject is similar to _each_with_object
# >> _each_with_object is similar to _zip
# >> _zip is faster than _map by 10.000000000000009% ± 10.0%
# >> 
# >> Running each test 2048 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> _each_with_object is similar to _inject
# >> _inject is faster than _zip by 19.999999999999996% ± 10.0%
# >> _zip is faster than _map by 10.000000000000009% ± 10.0%
# >> 
# >> Running each test 2048 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> _each_with_object is similar to _inject
# >> _inject is faster than _zip by 19.999999999999996% ± 10.0%
# >> _zip is faster than _map by 10.000000000000009% ± 10.0%
# >>
```

Answer (score 1):

A short solution using the [humanize](https://github.com/radar/humanize) gem for converting numbers to words.

```
require 'humanize'
array.group_by { |e| e.humanize.to_sym rescue :none }
# => {:one=>[1, 1], :two=>[2, 2], :three=>[3, 3, 3], :none=>[nil]}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
hash = array.group_by{|e| e}

[hash].each do |k|
   k[:one] = k.delete 1
   k[:two] = k.delete 2
   k[:three] = k.delete 3
   k[:none] = k.delete nil
end
```

you will get your output. If you dont want to loop do the following

```
hash[:one] = hash.delete 1
hash[:two] = hash.delete 2
hash[:three] = hash.delete 3
hash[:none] = hash.delete nil
```